# Cannot access Apache2 intranet site via VPN (can access other local resources)

Tags: apache-2.2, vpn, pptp

I'm having some problems accessing my Apache2 intranet site when connected to my network's VPN server.

My setup/environment:

- ASUS RT-66U router with PPTP VPN server.
- Debian server with apache 2.2 as "intranet server".
- LAN addresses are in the 10.0.0.0 network.

The intranet site  on the Apache2 server is configured so that only the LAN addresses have access (as below):

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

Allow from localhost

# IPv4
Allow from 127.0.0.0/8       # IPv4 Loopback Addresses
Allow from 169.254.0.0/16    # IPv4 Link-local Addresses
Allow from 10.0.0.0/8        # IPv4 Normal LAN Address Space
```

My ASUS RT-660U router is setup with a built-in PPTP VPN server, and I'm connecting to it with the Windows 7 built-in VPN client.

The VPN connection works fine with regards to the LAN; I can access network shares, SSH to the Linux/Apache2 server, and access the router's web interface at 10.0.0.1. So far, so good.

However, I cannot access the intranet virtual site on the Apache2 server. I can access this when connected to the LAN, and from the outside I get the `403 Forbidden` message. So basically it works as it should.

But when I connect to the VPN and try to open the intranet site, I still get the `403 Forbidden` message. This is, as mentioned, while having no problems accessing other LAN resources.

When I'm connected to the VPN, from my mobile network, this is Windows `ipconfig` info:

```
PPP adapter AEV25 VPN:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.200
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ccb5:407b:3314:5a66%12
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.206
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

The Windows 7 PC is connected to my Android phone's network (hotspot), then connected to the VPN.

From my basic understanding of networking, it seems that Apache2 uses the address of the Wireless LAN, which is connected to the "outside" through my mobile phone, and not the PPTP adapter address, which is the LAN address.

So, how can I get Apache2 to recognize the "correct" adapter/address, so that I can access the internal site via the VPN connection?

Answer (score 2):

What is the output of your `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and `/var/log/apache2/access.log`? That should provide some clues as to why it's being denied, and specifically, the client IP.

If you're using the wrong route to the server, make sure that you're giving the clients the right route. You should be sending them through the VPN gateway when they try to access the Intranet network.